# Finding the non-linear curve that minimize the (sum of squared) distance to a set of point

Tags: nonlinear-regression, curve-fitting, geometry, geography

I'm looking for the best approach to find the non-linear curve that minimize the mean square of perpendicular distance from a set of points. In essence, I would like to do non-linear major axis regression, with ideally being flexible in the shape of the curve (like when using splines in regression settings, or possibly high-level polynomials).

Any hint would be appreciated, as well as any information on possible R-based implementation.

I found the following reference that could provide guidance, but I haven't been able to access it (it seems to be only proceedings):
Akaho, S. 1998. Curve Fitting That Minimizes the Mean Square of Perpendicular Distances From Sample Points

Comment: It sounds like you are describing (nonlinear) total least squares as a method for dealing with errors in variables.  If so, see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/onls/onls.pdf  and its blog introduction     https://www.r-bloggers.com/introducing-orthogonal-nonlinear-least-squares-regression-in-r/ .

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Mark, looks like it can do the job indeed (although possibly not accommodating weird shapes as one has to explicitly define a formula for the fitted curve, i.e. being less flexible that splines).